# Opening file with associated program doesn't send its path in quotes

Tags: java, file, path, command-line-arguments

I have the following file that I'm trying to open with a program just like notepad that is made in java:
[image]

As you can see, it has a space in its path.
This is the value of args[0] when I open it by double-clicking on it:
`C:\Users\PC\Desktop\open`
When I run the program from cmd, while correctly specifying the path in quotes, it opens perfectly:
`notepad "c:\users\PC\desktop\open this.txt"`
I know I could easily handle this in java by merging all the arguments together to get the path, but I want to know if there is a better way.
If it matters, I'm using Launch4J to wrap the jar into an executable. Here is the code:

```
            try {
                savepath = args[0];
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, savepath, "This should be the full path",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                File editingFile = new File(savepath);
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(editingFile);
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    file += reader.nextLine() + '\n';
                }
                text.setText(file);
                reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "An error occured opening the file.", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

Comment: How are you running the java - if you've properly quoted the filename at launch it'll get a spec into the arg[0] in java? e.g.. `java -cp . Open "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\open this.txt"` should do the right sort of thing [obviously everything except quoting the filename is a guess since you didn't provide suffiicent details].

Comment: I'm using Launch4J to wrap the jar into an executable and then I just set it as a default program for .txt files.

Comment: but we have no idea how you are trying to open it... without code it is very hard to help - I *guess* there is a problem like the one of using `Runtime` and let it tokenize the command/arguments. Better include a [mcve] in question - or just a problem with `Launch4J`

Comment: Oh, sorry for the inconvenience, I edited the post to include the code I'm using to copy the contents from opened file to a textarea.

Comment: What does the dialog show when you try and open that file (or are the more args that just args[0]?

Comment: When I double-click it, yes. The arguments array would have "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\open" and "this.txt" because it splits the argument when it meets a space.

Comment: I don't know `Launch4J` but I would blame it - code seems good to me. Probably it is not correctly interpreting the arguments... maybe you must join all passed arguments (with space in between) ((or try

Comment: Yeah, I will do that. Seems like the best solution. Thanks for stopping by to help a stranger!

Comment: no problem!  (batch or shell scripts also are also *able* to mess up arguments)

Comment: What if you call from the command line `Launch4J.exe "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\open this.txt"` - if that works then you have some other options available.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I just fixed the problem by merging the arguments.
Launch4J is simply the wrapper I'm using and I don't see how starting it with an argument would help.